# Terminal unusable in Virtual Machine

Tags: graphics, gnome-terminal, virtualization

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I have created a virtual machine with the same ISO. In the virtual machine the terminal window shows up with a strange transparent gradient that makes it unusable. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: It seems that xterm works OK out of the box, it is the gnome-terminal that has the visual artifacts.

Comment: Please confirm or deny that this is a Qemu/KVM libvirt type VM. I know the exact problem and will make an answer.

Comment: @DougSmythies I _think_ it is, I followed the directions on http://www.howtogeek.com/117635/how-to-install-kvm-and-create-virtual-machines-on-ubuntu/. What can I run to check?

Comment: Could I ask you a question back about your VM: Does your screen turn back on after the screen lock time? Example: system-settings; brightness and screen lock; turn screen off when inactive for 1 minute; Lock screen on and after 30 seconds. Does the screen fade to black after 1 minute and then turn back on 30 seconds later?

Comment: @DougSmythies I'm sorry Doug, but I've moved on and deleted that VM. Your answer _did_ work and was the cause of the problem if that helps. It did make the GUI very very slow however, i.e. `gksudo` took about 20 seconds to "fade" the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default video driver for KVM/qemu libvirt type VMs is the cirrus driver and that is the root issue. Years ago, there were problems with the vmvga driver, and cirrus was made the default. Issues with the vmvga driver have long since been fixed.

For a new VM defintion, specify the vmvga driver.

To fix an existing VM then use `virsh edit` and change this line:

```
<model type='cirrus' vram='9216' heads='1'/>
```

to this:

```
<model type='vmvga' vram='9216' heads='1'/>
```

If the VM name is, for example, desk_tt then the defintion file will be `/etc/libvirt/qemu/desk_tt.xml`. Myself, I make a copy before changing things.

```
sudo cp desk_tt.xml desk_tt.xml.original
```

then, and you MUST use `virsh edit` do NOT edit the file directly, as `virsh edit` will do a bunch of checks upon save and exit. From any directory do:

```
virsh edit desk_tt
```

There is probably a way to make the change using `virt-manager`, but I do not use it, and so do not know how.

Note: the default editor used by `virsh edit` is as defined by the $EDITOR environment variable, or VI if it does not exist. add `export EDITOR="/bin/nano"` to your `~/.bashrc` file to set, for example, nano as your default editor.

Note: Readers might be tempted to increase the video ram, vram, in the above line, as depending on your screen size it probably isn't enough. At the time of posting this answer, the vram parmeter is ignored.

Comment: This is perhaps a silly question, but I can't seem to find where the VM is stored to edit it with virsh.  I can see that the image is stored in `/var/lib/libvirt/images` but trying to use `virsh` on that doesn't work.

Comment: answer expanded to include example. Hope that helps.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks. You might want to add to your answer the way to change the editor, I found that solution here: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-server/2011-March/005247.html

Comment: Yes, I found what I had done also. Will edit answer.

Answer (score 0):

The driver type can also be edited from the menu on the virtual machine terminal: View > Details > Video Cirrus

I selected VMVGA for the model, restarted the virtual machine and my terminals were no longer suffering from a transparent background.